# Weird codes or symbols printed to my log in the terminal

Tags: bash, cypress

I have a Cypress script running in the shell but when the log is printed, this is what I see:

```
19:37:34 [90m  ┌[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m─[39m[90m┐[39m
19:37:34 [90m  │[39m [90mCypress:[39m        6.3.0                                                                          [90m│[39m
19:37:34 [90m  │[39m [90mBrowser:[39m        Electron 87 [90m(headless)[39m
```

What should I add to my shell script to properly interpret these symbols `[90m─` and `[39m`?

Comment: Those are garbled escape sequences intended to change the font color/appearance. Can you tell Cypress not to colorize its output? If not, you'll need to figure out where along the line the escape sequences are getting garbled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Cypress documentations](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/introduction#Colors), if you want colors to be disabled, you can pass the `NO_COLOR` environment variable to disable colors.

So you would have a command like this:

```sh
NO_COLOR=1 cypress run
```

Comment: is it possible to set up in the cypress.json or it needs to be in the command line

Comment: @RosenMihaylov By looking at the documentation, it seems like this option can only be set through an enviornment variable and not the `cypress.json` file. But fee free to open an issue on [their GitHub repo](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues) requesting this feature.